# Cannot connect TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, team-explorer

I want to connect to TFS through the Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2015.
So, my problem is that I cannot connect because of a wrong authentication (valid username and password, valid privileges).

I think the reason for that is the Domain but I never joined one because I use a normal version of Windows 10 Enterprise. Could it depend on installed features like WCF? I did really intensive research but I'm not able to find any information to solve my problem.

Here is a screenshot of the Login-Dialog:

[image]

Comment: What version of TFS have and is it installed on the same machine as you are connecting from Visual Studio?

Comment: How do you configure the TFS server? Does it join any domain?

Comment: I added the image in the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to thank you for your support.
I'm sorry that this comes late but I already solved my problem.
I obviously just forgot to put a Backslash in front of my username so that I don't use the domain of my local computer.

Answer (score 0):

On premise TFS only supports Windows auth (either local or domain).

If your TFS server and VS are installed on the same machine, you could use your local account with enough permission to connect TFS server directly.

If your TFS server and VS are installed on the different machine, and since you haven't joined domain. Suggest you to **join domain** : This is the easiest to setup, user-wise. All you have to do is be a member of the domain and a member in a team project. Another option is using  *Visual Studio Team Service* (TFS in the cloud) for this. It's currently free and uses Microsoft live accounts instead. Which you can access it everywhere on the internet.